# My Image Doesn't Look Like It Supposed To Look

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogs

Currently, I am watching a YouTube Tutorial to make blog website. Our code is the same, but my image doesn't look like it looks in the video. My code is below.

You can see the tutorial from the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtRTmkd5Nsg&list=LL&index=18

```css
  /* HERO SECTION */

  .hero{
    background: var(--background-primary);
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: var(--py);
    text-align: center;
  }

  .hero .h1{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }

  .hero b{
    color: var(--accent);
    font-weight: inherit;
  }

  .hero .h3{
    color: var(--foreground-secondary);
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .hero .btn-group{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 15px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .hero .right{
    display: none;
  }
  
      /* HERO SECTION */

    .hero{
        text-align: left;
    }

    .hero .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 50px;
    }

    .hero .btn-group{
        justify-content: start;
        gap: 30px;
    }

    .hero .right{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .hero .pattern-bg{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background: url(../images/pattern.png);
        background-size: contain;
        opacity: 0.2;
    }

    .hero .img-box{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .hero-img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
        border-radius: 0 0 280px 230px;
        transform: translate(10px , -10px);
    }

    .hero .shape {
        position: absolute;
        top:  50%;
        left: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -42%) rotate(-20deg);
      }
    
      .hero .shape-1 {
        background: var(--accent);
        width:  90%;
        height: 90%;
        z-index: -1;
      }
    
      .hero .shape-2 {
        width:  92%;
        height: 92%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 -30px 0 var(--action-primary);
        z-index: 2;
      }
```

```html
<!-- HERO SECTION -->
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="left">
                    <h1 class="h1">
                        Hello World! I'm <b> Buse&nbsp;Nur </b>,
                        <br> Web Developer
                    </h1>
                    <p class="h3">
                        Specalized in <abbr title="Accessibility">ally</abbr>
                        and Core Web Vitals
                    </p>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Contact Me </a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary"> About Me </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <div class="pattern-bg">
                        <div class="img-box">
                            <img src="./images/profile.jpg" width="500px" height="500px" alt="Buse Nur Çetin" class="hero-img">
                            <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
                            <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _Our codes are same but my image doesn't look like it look in the video_ - what should the image look like? Take a screenshot of that in the video and add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="pattern-bg">
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="./images/profile.jpg" width="500px" height="500px" alt="Buse Nur Çetin" class="hero-img">
    <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
    <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the block above, the image is placed within the div that has the class "pattern-bg" this affects all the elements within that div, including the profile image. The div with the "img-box" class must be out of the div with class "pattern-bg" to have it display the way you want, that is with a full opacity.

```
<div class="pattern-bg"></div>
<div class="img-box">
    <img src="./images/profile.jpg" width="500px" height="500px" alt="Buse Nur Çetin" class="hero-img">
    <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
    <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
  </div>
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: thank you it helped a lot but still purple background is not exist for me

Comment: Try changing the z-index of class "shape-1" to 1. It might work